# Beveling an edge inside an empty space

Tags: edges, bevel

I am trying to bevel the edges (picture 1) but when I bevel it, instead of just the edges beveling the whole geomtery(picture 2) becomes a solid block.

I have tried various things but I can't seem to created a curved edge inside the space.Any help/tip would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

I would like to create a curved edge like the one in the 3rd image, it worked here but its not working for the other side(1st Image)

[image]

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with this, make sure, scale & rotation are applied:

[image]

add boolean modifier to the big cube:

[image]

set visibility of small cube to bounds:

[image]

[image]

now add bevel to small box:

[image]

or instead of using bevel modifier if you just want to bevel the edges, select these edges:

[image]

CTRL-B -> move mouse and use scroll wheel to increase loop cuts number.

[image]

--- update

do this to with your uploaded version:

1. select cube2
2. tab -> edit mode
3. M -> merge by distance -> A
4. then select your edges and bevel:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for your response, I understand your approach, I used the same way you mentioned by using boolean modifer and setting the visibiliy of the small cube to bounds, but I am just curious to know for the sake of understanding when I select the edges (exactly like how you selected them) and bevel , instead of the edges beveling, the empty space is filled by a solid shape like in image 2(The one I posted) whereas i did the same thing (as shown in image 3) on the other side and it worked fine. What is causing this to happen?

Comment: Pls provide your blend file so I can check it out

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=rbJVKXdb" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/rbJVKXdb/)

Comment: Any chance you checked it:?

Comment: you had double vertices -> you can delete them in edit mode with A -> select all, then M ...i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me understand:)

Comment: you are welcome